# Pinging sometimes buggy?

Tags: discussion, bug, notifications

Sometimes, I don't get notified if someone addresses me using "@username" in either a thread where I have posted or below one of my posts. At first I thought it's me missing the pings when I get several at once but it's definitely not.

The other thing about notifications I noticed is funny. So I got a ping saying "2 answers ..." for [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209718/question-about-definition-of-regular-projection-of-a-knot). But as +10k users will readily find out, there is only one answers.

I assumed that if one is quick enough to delete a post it gets ignored by the system. But now that pinging seems to be buggy and also, since I got notified for 2 answers, I thought I'd post on meta.

Here is a screenshot for when I got pinged for 2 answers when there only is one:

[image]

Comment: I guess it's not a vital feature to have bug-free pinging but I thought you might want to know anyway.

Comment: Similar post at meta.SO: [Incorrect number of answers displayed in notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141290/incorrect-number-of-answers-displayed-in-notification)